# get yaml files instead of application.properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

What i want is to generate application.yaml file for spring boot configration instead of application.properties using openapi 3 generators.
I want to ask is it possible?
currently openapi 3 generate a application.propeties file when api generate task gets executed.

Comment: openapi-generator is (usually) used to generate source code. It expects an openapi yaml file as input and does generate server or client side code for your api. To generate an api yaml from the source code you could use springfox.  application.yaml/properties are spring boot configuration files which don't have anything to do with openapi.

Comment: thanks @MartinHauner for reply, yes you are right initally I was serching for this due to openapi generating application.properties and overriding my properties file. later got to know that we can ignore properties file generation.